# What is the purpose of feed wire and return wire in electric railway?

Tags: power-supply

Looking at the following image:

[image]

<sub>Image source: [The Railway Technical Website](http://www.railway-technical.com/infrastructure/electric-traction-power.html)</sub>

On the left of the mast there are two cables, feed wire and return wire.

Are they acting like a ground cable which usually is made by the rail working as a ground conductor?

They are not always present in the railway electrification system, which is why I am not sure about their role.

Comment: If the rail has insulated joints (e.g. for signaling) the return current can’t be carried long distances by it.

Comment: So installing feed wire and return wire is a solution? But why two wires and not only one (return line)?

Comment: The return current is carried by the ground @τεκ. This is a good question, my guess would be to avoid having transient voltage on the Mast or in case there is a short circuit with the powered line the it would activate the breaker immediately and not perhaps blow the concrete base or have the mast at 40kV.

Comment: Where did the picture come from - it doesn't look like the standard 25 kV AC system used around the UK. It looks like tram overhead cables i.e. much smaller voltage than 25 kV.

Comment: @Andy aka - Photo is from http://www.railway-technical.com/infrastructure/electric-traction-power.html - A section of the Old Dalby test track in England showing both third rail and overhead electrification. Both systems are provided to allow train testing from the main line or London Underground. The 3rd rail system is common around the world but the 4th rail is rare. London Underground is the largest user of the 4-rail system in the world.